# How to convert `proportion var1, over(var2)` in Stata to R

Tags: r, stata

I usually use the command `proportion var1, over(var2)` in Stata to get the proportions of var1 stratified by var2.

I'm wondering how can I do this in `R`?

Stata output:

```
. prop CS_RACA2, over(SEM_PRI_CAT2 )



Proportion estimation             Number of obs   =      6,613



       Branca: CS_RACA2 = Branca

        Preta: CS_RACA2 = Preta

        Parda: CS_RACA2 = Parda

     Ignorado: CS_RACA2 = Ignorado

      _prop_5: CS_RACA2 = Amarela/Indigena



    _subpop_1: SEM_PRI_CAT2 = 1 a 16

    _subpop_2: SEM_PRI_CAT2 = 17 a 21

    _subpop_3: SEM_PRI_CAT2 = 22 a 25

    _subpop_4: SEM_PRI_CAT2 = 26 a 29



--------------------------------------------------------------

        Over | Proportion   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]

-------------+------------------------------------------------

Branca       |

   _subpop_1 |   .3179625   .0107862      .2972029    .3394717

   _subpop_2 |   .3071672   .0120568      .2840509    .3312943

   _subpop_3 |   .2307692   .0095756      .2125342     .250072

   _subpop_4 |   .2340267   .0115446       .212159    .2574121

-------------+------------------------------------------------

Preta        |

   _subpop_1 |   .0825737    .006375      .0709064    .0959625

   _subpop_2 |   .0798635   .0070848       .067032    .0949014

   _subpop_3 |   .1104801   .0071247      .0972671    .1252391

   _subpop_4 |   .0676077    .006846       .055361    .0823276

-------------+------------------------------------------------

Parda        |

   _subpop_1 |   .4541555   .0115322      .4316582    .4768415

   _subpop_2 |   .4627986   .0130315      .4373723      .48842

   _subpop_3 |   .4889004   .0113608      .4666662    .5111786

   _subpop_4 |   .4940565   .0136326      .4673746    .5207723

-------------+------------------------------------------------

Ignorado     |

   _subpop_1 |   .1383378   .0079968      .1233938    .1547721

   _subpop_2 |   .1392491   .0090482      .1224397    .1579509

   _subpop_3 |   .1641714   .0084189      .1483267    .1813482

   _subpop_4 |   .1953938   .0108115      .1750653    .2174605

-------------+------------------------------------------------

_prop_5      |

   _subpop_1 |   .0069705    .001927      .0040507    .0119698

   _subpop_2 |   .0109215   .0027164      .0066996    .0177564

   _subpop_3 |   .0056789   .0017078      .0031468    .0102274

   _subpop_4 |   .0089153   .0025631      .0050683    .0156366

--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe `prop.table(xtabs(~ var2 + var1))`? Can you post sample data and expected output? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: and how to obtain the values of `Std. Err.` and  `[95% Conf. Interval]` present in STATA? Maybe it should be apart?

Comment: Are you asking for the % of var1 grouped by var2? You can do this with `dplyr` (a standard data wranging r package) verbs.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave a couple rows of sample data, and a complete description of the output you want in the question.

Comment: A few R packages calculate 95 CI,  ‘PropCIs’ is one of them

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(var2) %>%
   mutate(prop = var1 / sum(var2))
```

Edit: `%>%`inserted

Comment: this approach gives me the proportions, but in addition, the command `prop var1, over (var2)` gives me the confidence interval. I'm sorry I can't tell you how it was calculated, but this command shows me those values.

Comment: You can use `binom.test` to get the confidence interval, and maybe the `broom` package to clean it up into a nicer output.

Comment: What `proportion` does in Stata is documented and R users too can read that. https://www.stata.com/manuals/rproportion.pdf At the same time, a good question would explain the default method, not expect that R people would do the work of finding that out.